# Spree plugin for list-only products

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm setting up a Spree store and I'm wondering if there's a plugin which allows me to set products to a "not for sale" state? Criteria is:

- product is still listed
- product still has a price
- product cannot be added to cart
- message with product explaining that it must be purchased in store

I'm currently trawling through the Spree plugins to see if anything fits the bill. Will report back if I find anything, otherwise I'll write my own :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the stock to `0` for the items which you want in the `not for sale` state. Doing this won't set the state to `not for sale` but you will be able to achieve the following 3 things :

- product is still listed
- product still has a price
- product cannot be added to cart

I hope this helps.